# Excel VBA 2013 Customised Sub only Pasted not executed in cell with use of FormulaR1C1

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013, custom-formatting

I've written a specific sub for formatting data from another cell.

```
Sub Macro3()
    '>> First record to get the original code in Testing.xlsm <<
    Range("F5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=fG_ReFormattingInvoiceNumber(RC[-3],3)"
    Range("H5").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    '>>> I wrote in my application this line => ReInvoicingWBook.Sheets _
    '    (G_sheetNameREINVOICinG).Range("U5").FormulaR1C1 = _
    '    "=fG_ReFormattingInvoiceNumber(RC[-19],3)"
End Sub
```

The problem is that `ReInvoicingWBook.Sheets(G_sheetNameREINVOICinG).Range("U5")` Cell is just filled with the formula but it is not executed.

`ReInvoicingWBook` is a file opened by the Excel application I'm developing and writing inside it.

Yet, calling to `fG_ReFormattingInvoiceNumber()` works nice in the original file `Testing.xlsm`/ Sub `Macro3`  where I captured VBA lines.

The 1st thing I see is the fact that `ReInvoicingWBook` is a pointer to a file XLSM that is monitored by my application. Perhaps, it's a reason...

Any solution or help from you are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force a calculation of cells by using `.Calculate`.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Range("F5").FormulaR1C1 = "=fG_ReFormattingInvoiceNumber(RC[-3],3)"
    Range("F5").Calculate
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

As a general rule, **always** use `Option Explicit`, avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate`. Also, fully qualify your ranges (which is something I have not done in the example above because I have no context).

Comment: '>>> ATTENTION si Ajout de Colonnes <<<

 ReInvoicingWBook.Sheets(G_sheetNameREINVOICinG).Range("U" & 
iNoLine2Write).FormulaR1C1 = "=fG_ReFormattingInvoiceNumber(RC[-19],3)"
    ReInvoicingWBook.Sheets(G_sheetNameREINVOICinG).Range("U" & iNoLine2Write).Calculate
   '>>> And I use Option Explicit in the monitoring application.

But it does not work... Once again, the formula is just pasted.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why it doesn't work : the cell was formatted in Text whereas it must be as General. It's fine now.